# Descartar contenido de la busqueda de un archivo - Perl

Tags: perl

Actualmente estoy construyendo un script para buscar un codigo en un documento que tiene "x" cantidad de texto, hasta ahora puedo conseguir los matchs o coincidencias pero no logro traerme solo el código ya que me trae toda la linea donde el codigo es encontrado, exactamente quiero descartar todo el texto y que me traiga solamente el codigo 
"500 5.1.1" Si es que se encuentra dentro del documento. Cualquier ayuda estaría muy agradecido!

```html
use strict;
use warnings;

my $resultado;

open (BUSCAR, "<", "/home/lserrano/Documentos/perl/files/devueltos2018ls.txt");

while (<BUSCAR>){
  if(m/([5])\1(0)/){
    $resultado = $_;
    print $resultado;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No nos dices qué aspecto deben tener los códigos.

Si suponemos que los códigos tienen la forma de un número de tres dígitos, seguido de une espacio, seguido por una secuencia de números intercalados con puntos, podemos usar este patrón:

```perl
while (<BUSCAR>){
  if(m/(\d{3}\s\d[.]\d[.]\d)/){
    $resultado = $1;    # el resultado está en el primer par de paréntesis
    print $resultado;
  };
}
```

Comment: Saludos, si coloquè que aspecto debe tener el codigo, debo traerme solo este codigo "550 5.1.1" o las variantes pero no deseo traerme mas texto, con el codigo que me colocaste el busca ese codigo pero se trae toda la linea yo necesito es descartar toda la linea y traerme solamente el codigo.

Comment: ¿Seguro que la has copiado bien? Fíjate que pone $1 en lugar de $_, que es donde tenías el error...

Comment: el problema lo pude resolver a través de un stric, con $1 igual me traia la linea.

Comment: ¿Con un strict? Sería interesante ver el resultado. ¿Puedes publicarlo en el foro de perlenespanol.com?

Comment: Seguro dame unos minutos, porque estoy todavia estudiando porque ciertas validaciones no se cumplen a pesar de que el codigo en teoria esta correcto, es un codigo que funcionaba y de un dìa para otro dejo de funcionar.

Comment: Disculpa la funcino es substr no strict confundi el nombre de las funciones.